# how to perform t-test on multiple columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, statistics

I have df that consists of 7 columns each corresponding to a chromosome. I would like to see if the values in each of the chromosome is statistically significant with other chromosomes. Here is the sub-set of the df...

```
       A01      A02       A03       A04       A05       A06       A07
1 0.0475424 0.224646 0.1065940 0.1580800 0.0279520 0.8189890 0.2721350
2 0.0383661 0.133959 0.0579846 0.0300916 0.1662380 0.0735981 0.2863390
3 0.2999830 0.407670 0.1696190 0.0379608 0.0544481 0.1532610 0.1041220
4 0.1605930 0.729948 0.0642579 0.4513340 0.3155020 0.3234300 0.7930150
5 0.5301730 0.100597 0.1850310 0.1111630 0.1000220 0.2172030 0.0748173
6 0.0268711 1.278470 0.0958172 0.5504090 0.3600080 0.0355549 0.3678820
```

I know i can just use `t-test` to compare "A01" to "A02" and so on. But it will tell me if those two chromosome are significant or not but my plan is to compare `A01` with all other chromosomes. How can i do that?

Thanks

Upendra

Comment: Aside from any technicalities, this seems a little dubious from a statistical/data fishing point of view.

Answer (score 1):

You could reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661469/r-t-test-over-all-columns), which was the first link when Googling *"t test multiple columns R"*.

Using the `reshape2` package and a `pairwise.t.test`, and assuming `dat` is your data...

```
> library(reshape2)
> meltdf <- melt(dat)
> pairwise.t.test(meltdf$value, meltdf$variable, p.adjust = "none")
#  Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 
# 
# data:  meltdf$value and meltdf$variable 
# 
#     A01   A02   A03   A04   A05   A06  
# A02 0.056 -     -     -     -     -    
# A03 0.639 0.019 -     -     -     -    
# A04 0.794 0.095 0.466 -     -     -    
# A05 0.930 0.046 0.703 0.727 -     -    
# A06 0.566 0.171 0.300 0.754 0.509 -    
# A07 0.381 0.283 0.182 0.536 0.336 0.760
# 
# P value adjustment method: none
```

Comment: I saw the reference link but still posted the question since i am not interested in pairwise comparisons but would like to compare each chromosome with the rest of 6 chromosomes. Can this be done?

Comment: You mean like `A01 ~ all the others`, then `A02 ~ all the others`, etc?

Comment: That's right @Richard. `A01 vs all (except A01)`, then `A02 vs all (except A02)` and so on.....

Comment: Are you sure you want a t-test then?  t-tests just compares all the variables with a null hypothesis: mean equals zero.  You may want analysis of variance.

Comment: you mean i can do this `aov(lm(dat1$A01 ~ dat$notA01))` and the `notA01` is summing of all the rows in the `dat` except `AO1`?

Answer (score 0):

Welch-test can be used to compare the means of normally distributed vectors with different lengths and standard errors. That test is the one used by default in R `t.test()`function.

Therefore, I guess you could do what you want aggregating all vectors from A02 to the end and compare it with A01 with `t.test`(if they are normally distributed, which you can check with `ks.test`or `shapiro.test`).

Then, have the tested vector varying with a loop and that should do the trick.

However, you will have to fix the multiple testing issue manually (which is not so hard).