# t-test for multiple columns of dataframe

Tags: r

I have a  hourly PM10 data from 2014 to 2019 and it has 4 stations. I want to apply t-test on these stations to compare their values. My data contains only 4 columns which names are bafra, atakum, canik, and ilkadim (stations names).

This link is related my question but it always gived error.

[R: t test over multiple columns using t.test function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48907955/r-t-test-over-multiple-columns-using-t-test-function)

I tried this code; but I want to show my results as a more clear such as results with station name, p value, conf. interval...

```
library(reshape2)
meltdf <- melt(samsun)
pairwise.t.test(meltdf$value, meltdf$Var2, p.adjust = "none")
```

How can i do?

Comment: What error do you get exactly? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Define `samsun` with some sample data.

Comment: Actually, codes runned but when I clicked results, it gave zero.